# Detecting external keyboard Key Down Events in IOS without EditText Field

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard, external, keydown

I'm trying to detect key pressed for an external keyboard (via bluetooth) with an 4th generation iPad. I was only able to do so when the focus is on a `EditText` Field.
Without the edit text field, the key down events aren't captured by the program. Is there any work around for this issue?

I've tried to following, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
-(NSArray *) keyCommands
{

}
```